# Installing wxPython on centos machine using python 2.7

Tags: python, centos, wxpython

I am installing WxPython 3.0 on centos machine with python 2.7.

even with disable-mediactrl the install searches for GSTreamer and gives the error

```
configure: error: GStreamer not available
```

despite the fact that GSTreamer is available on the machine.

Here are the details for two such builds:

My idea was to turn OFF mediactrl, so I am using following option

```
python build-wxpython.py --extra_setup=disable-mediactrl  --build_dir=../bld
```

or

```
python build-wxpython.py --extra_setup="--disable-mediactrl  --build_dir=../bld
```

However, it still searches for GSTreamer and outputs the error message listed below. I reinstalled GSTreamer 0.10 and into `\usr\lib\GSTreamer 0.10`, however, I receive the same error message

error message :

```
checking what is the type of the third argument of getsockname... socklen_t checking what is the type of the fifth argument of getsockopt... socklen_t checking for linux/joystick.h... yes checking for python... /home/aptRoot/tools/python/64/Python-2.7/bin/python checking for WEBKIT... configure: WARNING: webkitgtk not found. configure: WARNING: WebKit not available, disabling wxWebView checking for CAIRO... yes checking for cairo_push_group... yes checking for GST... configure: WARNING: GStreamer 0.10 not available, falling back to 0.8 checking for GST... configure: WARNING: GStreamer 0.8/0.10 not available. configure: error: GStreamer not available Error running configure ERROR: failed building wxWidgets Traceback (most recent call last):   File "build-wxpython.py", line 378, in <module>
    wxbuild.main(wxscript, build_options)   File "/home/hemadris/iAPT/install/wxPython-src-3.0.0.0/build/tools/build-wxwidgets.py", line 364, in main
    "Error running configure")   File "/home/hemadris/iAPT/install/wxPython-src-3.0.0.0/build/tools/build-wxwidgets.py", line 80, in exitIfError
    raise builder.BuildError(msg) BuildError
```

Answer (score 4):

I found that doing `yum install gstreamer-plugins-base-devel` gives it the dependencies it needs. Head over to the [wx](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wx/3.0.3) PyPi page to see the list of dependencies.

Comment: Installing `gstreamer1-plugins-base-devel` didn't allow the `wx` installation to succeed for me. However, after installing `gstreamer-plugins-base-devel` (without "1") it worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

Even I have tried installin wxPython 3.0.0.0 version on centos 6.4 but faced the same error

Try this command

```
rpm -qa | grep gstreamer
```

..to check if gstreamer development packages are available in your OS or not .

If not then run the configure,make,make install command

If we follow the build approach then too there is some error in _html.cpp